# proc sort, retain in R

Tags: r, sas

how first.variable and retain work in R.

```
df <- data.frame(inst = c('a', 'a', 'a','a','b', 'b', 'b','b'), 
                 sample = c('pa', 'pa', 'pc','pc', 'pa', 'pa', 'pc','pc'),
                 testdate = c("04/29/2019","04/30/2019", "04/29/2019","04/30/2019", "04/29/2019","04/30/2019", "04/29/2019","04/30/2019"), 
                 run = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))


proc sort data=c1; by inst sample testdate; run;
data c1;
    set c1;
    by inst sample testdate;
    if first.sample then day=0;
    if first.testdate then day+1;
run;
```

day column should be 1,2 in each inst and sample.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert this SAS code to R code? Or are you asking what's happening in SAS?

Comment: @Reeza, Asking R code similar to SAS.

Comment: Please follow these guidelines in the future [ask].

Comment: Will you ever have repeat dates?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. FYI - in the future please show example data, what you expect as output and what you've tried so far.

```
library(tidyverse)

#adds in dataset

mpg<-mpg

#Add group counter where each year has the same group number

#within each manufacture/model combination

mpg2 <- mpg %>%
    #grouping variables (testdate would not be in your list)
    group_by(manufacturer, model) %>%
    mutate(day = row_number(), run = cumsum(c(TRUE, year[-1] != year[-n()]))))
```

Comment: this did not generate the result I wanted.  I now generated reproducible result with expected output.

Comment: I've modified my answer, but if you have repeat dates it won't work as expected in comparison to your SAS code.

Comment: how do you deal with if you have duplicate dates nested within inst and sample. your code only deals with distinct date values in each of the groups. for example if you have 2 same dates nested withing inst one and sample 1 then I need to say day 1,1 so forth... I think you get my point

Comment: never mind. I found a way by taking distinct values and using row_number() you provided earlier and then merged with back the whole data that worked. Thanks

Comment: My original answer would have dealt with that. in the future please take the time to ensure your data is presented in a manner that reflects your situation.